# Does Raspbian come with a remote desktop (RDP) client?

Tags: raspbian, rdp

Do you know if the Raspberry Pi's recommended OS Raspbian comes with a remote desktop (RDP) client as default, or one that I can download to remote desktop into a Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Remmina

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

to install [Remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/).

## rdesktop

You could also try [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) by running

```
sudo apt-get install rdesktop
```

Answer (score 5):

Try install [TightVNC Server](http://raspi.tv/2012/install-and-use-tightvnc-remote-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-through-windows-android-or-ios) on Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

Run it every time or add it to startup:

```
/usr/bin/tightvncserver
```

You will need a [TightVNC Client](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) on your Windows PC o Android Phone.

Comment: I think the OP wants a [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) client for the RPi, not a server. He wants to log in his Windows 7 RPD server.

Comment: Hi Cerobot, I'm afraid I was looking for an RDP, not VNC client.

Comment: With VNC, the server is the client.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the [Raspberry Pi Thin Client project](http://rpitc.blogspot.nl/) on a Raspberry Pi 2 on a screen with a resolution of 2560 x 1440 pixels. Was a little bit slow on building the screen but much better than installing it under Raspbian.