# Remote Desktop connection (RDP) to Raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc, rdp

I read about [RDP on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2130/5556), but how about the **Raspbmc** desktop; is there a way to do a remotely connect into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the real answer lies in the [Raspbmc FAQ](http://www.raspbmc.com/wiki/user/frequently-asked-questions/):

> **Q: Can I run a VNC server on Raspbmc?**
>
> **A: No.** VNC relies on the X11 window system, but Raspbmc’s XBMC implementation is rendered in the framebuffer only. Thus VNC cannot be used as there is no X-session available for connection.

RDP, just like VNC, relies on the X11 window system—the same limitation applies:

[image: xRDP on Raspbmc: unable to starts X session]

Comment: As per http://www.raspbmc.com/2013/07/raspbmcs-july-update/ vnc is included on Raspbmc, trying to figure out how to enable it.

Answer (score 3):

You can login to your Raspbmc using ssh. Once logged in install [XRDP](http://www.xrdp.org/) (Or any other of the RDP solutions [Remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/), [rDesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/)) All ways to install these are in the other [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2130/5556) you mentioned.

**How to install XRDP**
Run the following command once your logged into your Raspberry Pi over SSH.

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

How to make it [run at boot](http://www.xrdp.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13:xrdp-start-on-boot&catid=2:documents&Itemid=7).
Following is from the link, more elaborate ways can be found with Google.

With LSB tags, you can:

1. add: `update-rc.d xrdp defaults`
2. remove: `update-rc.d xrdp remove`

Comment: This solution works on **Raspbian** and other flavours that come with the **X11** window system.